# ActiveStorage::Current.host= is deprecated, how can i use ActiveStorage::Current.url_options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I render urls for my active record attachments in erb files with **url** method.

```
#controller    
class RecordMetadataController < ApplicationController
        before_action do
        ActiveStorage::Current.host = request.base_url
      end
    .
    .
    .
    end


#view
    <iframe src="<%= file.url expires_in: 30 ,disposition: :inline %>" width="600" height="750" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

Rails gives **DEPRECATION WARNING** in my console so i tried to  update my code but i cant make it work.

```
***DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveStorage::Current.host= is deprecated, instead use ActiveStorage::Current.url_options***
```

### updatded code

```
#controller
...
ActiveStorage::Current.url_options = request.base_url
...
```

### new error

**in web console i am trying to get full url for file**

```
>> file.url
ArgumentError: Cannot generate URL for K01_D01_G12.pdf using Disk service, please set ActiveStorage::Current.url_options.
```

can anybody help?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`ActiveStorage::Current.url_options` is actually a Hash that has separate keys for `protocol`, `host`, and `port`. Thus you would need:

```rb
before_action do
  ActiveStorage::Current.url_options = { protocol: request.protocol, host: request.host, port: request.port }
end
```

Alternatively, ActiveStorage provides a concern (`ActiveStorage::SetCurrent`) that does just that. So, you should be able to do the following:

```rb
class RecordMetadataController < ApplicationController
  include ActiveStorage::SetCurrent
  ...
end
```

Comment: Hi @rmlockerd, i'm getting ActionView::Template::Error: Cannot generate URL for banner.jpeg using Disk service, please set ActiveStorage::Current.url_options
When sending mail locally, where can I set the "url_options" in my case? Thank you!

Comment: I didn't need to include ActiveStorage::SetCurrent to get the desired behavior, but a huge gotcha is that `url_for` acts differently in the controller and the view. The view doesn't bring the host with it.

Comment: The include was all I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @aldrien.h For ActionMailer, I placed this snippet that makes the ActiveStorage url options rely on that of ActionMailer's default_url_options:
```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  before_action do
    ActiveStorage::Current.url_options = ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

**Note**: If you are seeing this in `rspec` then follow this

You can put this `spec/rails_helper.rb` file

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Fixes Error after Rails 7.0 upgrade
  #   "Cannot generate URL for 50by50.gif using Disk service, please set ActiveStorage::Current.url_options".
  ActiveStorage::Current.url_options = {host: "https://www.example.com"}
```